# Looping a set of queries of in Pyspark running very slow

Tags: python, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running 3 queries in pyspark in single job. First query is executed then result of this query is used in 2nd query and result of 2nd is used in 3rd query. Finally , 3rd query is saved.

The job is taking hours . I have a 15 Instance cluster of spark and 32 GB memory each instance with 8 cores.  Would need help in optimizing this scenario.

All these queries are being ran in loop as follows:

for id in stores: 
  Execute Query- 1
  Execute Query-2 
  Execute Query -3

Then save final output.

For loop iterates 2400 times.

Comment: Can you include the Spark execution plan? For example, by running `df.explain()` on your resulting df after 2 loops.

Comment: @cylim How do i post explain plan here? It spans over more than 3-4 pages

Comment: If the execution plan cannot fit in question edit, can you show the pyspark code that you have within the loop and how you retrieve the final result?

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to optimise your PySpark code by reviewing the common issues listed here, https://www.enigma.com/blog/things-i-wish-id-known-about-spark. My suspicion is that you have pyspark operations shuffle data such as `join` and `groupBy` inside your for loop.

Comment: @ cylim.. Thanks for sharing above link.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using dataframes iteratively is slow

- Using Dataframes iteratively in for loops etc is slow because it leads to massive query plans. This issue is detailed [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13346)
- The suggested solution is convert to an rdd and back again. For example - [credit to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492194/for-iterative-algorithms-what-is-the-advantage-of-converting-to-an-rdd-then-b):

  ```
  val rdd = df.rdd
  rdd.cache()
  sqlCtx.createDataFrame(rdd. df.schema)
  ```
- Another solution is to use [checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.checkpoint).

  ```
  From the spark documentation:
  Checkpointing can be used to truncate the logical plan of this DataFrame,
  which is especially useful in iterative algorithms where the plan may grow exponentially. 
  It will be saved to files inside the checkpoint directory set with SparkContext.setCheckpointDir().
  ```
- I'm not sure whether or not this has been resolved in spark 3.X as the issue has just been marked resolved with no explanation of any actions taken